# How optimize fetch and related objects loading?

Tags: python, django-models, fetch

I am beginer with django, and after few hours passed to looking for a solution I finally ask for help. I would like to find the best way (performance) to retrieve/fetch data with my model. I tried a couple of things and I read documentation about select_related, prefetch_related.

**The concret probleme is :**

I have a list of specific_id, retrieved from a web service, and i need to load the correpondings objects (in the right order given by the list) and with some related objects.

**My model :**

I have a product with 0-N repositories related (FK from Repository).
This product have also 0-N sources (couple of 0-N Sensor and  0-N Platform), through sourcecontribtoproduct

```
class Product(models.Model):
    specific_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False, blank=True, null=False)

class Repository(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=2048, blank=True, null=True)

class SourceContribToProduct(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)

class Source(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='SourceContribToProduct')
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform, blank=True, null=True)
    sensor = models.ForeignKey(Sensor, blank=True, null=True)

class Sensor(models.Model):
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    type = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Platform(models.Model):
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

So, as I said, I need to retrieve a list of products with all Repository, Sources and Plateform loaded. Here is what I have done in my views.py

```
# Retrive list of objects
products = Product.objects.filter(specific_id__in=ids).prefetch_related('repository_set', 'source_set')
for p in products:
    p.repositories = p.repository_set.all()
    p.sources = Source.objects.filter(sourcecontribtoproduct__product_id=p.id).select_related('sensor_set', 'platform_set')
    for s in p.sources:
        s.sensor
        s.platform

# Sort the list
products = list(products)
products.sort(key=lambda t: ids.index(t.specific_id))
```

What do you think of this code ? How could I optimize this treatment, cause I feel this is too long. I only have 194 products (max 5 repository related, and not more than 3 sources) and my browser need around 5 seconds to show the result. Is there a way to simply load nested / related object by default ?

Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found out how to solve my interrogation, I don't need to iterate on objects in the view to load them. Just need to create a query set and acces in the template. Like this:

In the view.py

`products=Product.objects.filter(specific_id__in=ids).prefetch_related('repository_set', 'source_set').select_related('repository_set', 'source_set')`

Then in my template, iterate on :

```
{% for src in product.source_set.all %}
   {{src.platform.shortname}} / {{src.sensor.shortname}}<br/>
{% endfor %}


{% for repo in product.repository_set.all %}
   {{repo.url}}%}
{% endfor %}
```

That's all...